# What is the pipe\srvsvc named pipe for

Tags: named-pipes, windows-server-2012-r2, smb

Watching WriteFile operations with Procmon I noticed that MPC-HC writes to `\\MYSERVER\PIPE\srvsvc`. What is the purpose of this named pipe on Windows Server 2012 R2 ? I read very detailed articles and did't understand. I need some big picture of that.